# Redux store should be one for each module or one for whole application comprising of a multiple mudules

Tags: angularjs, redux, components, angular-redux

I am integrating or sort of rewriting my Angular 1 application with Redux. It has the following architecture:

`app1 => App1 running on diff subdomain 
app2 => App2 running on diff subdomain 
and so on... 
shared => Shared modules(with multiple components) b/w app1 and app2`

An app is made of **multiple modules** specific to it. 
Shared directory has one or many modules that are **shared between two or more apps**

So my question is should I have app level store or a module level store.

By app level store and module level store I mean, for example:

1. Let's say we have a shared module `SM1` which is shared between two apps.
2. `SM1` should use the store of `app1` when used inside `app1` and should use the store of `app2` when used inside `app2`. But a module should be a self-sustained entity and it should not rely on any other thing for its store.
3. Or the `SM1` could have its own store not sharing with any app. But when the `SM1` is used inside `app1` will its store conflict with the store of `app1`.
4. Also if I use a module level store then the module and the app both need to be provided with the `ngRedux` dependencies which seem kind of redundant.

What is the best solution here in terms of a scalable architecture and `redux` core principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for loose coupling as much as you can:

- app1 - own store (integrates sm store)
- app2 - own store (integrates sm store)
- sm   - own store

Answer (score 1):

[redux-subspace](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-subspace) was created for a very similar use case (in fact, we have also been migrating 2 seperate apps from angular 1 to react/redux with shared components between them).  It allows you to have a single store and isolate a section of it for your shared components.

The basic concept is that the parent app combine's the component's reducer into it's store and then sub stores are created that return a reduced state tree and namespace dispatched actions.

Note: I have not use angular w/ redux and I have no idea how you integrate the two, so I'm only going to show how you can create the sub-stores and hope it works for you (if you do get it working, I'd love to know so we can expand our supported frameworks in our docs).

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { subspace, namespaced } from 'redux-subspace'

const component1 = (state = { value: 1 }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return { ...state, value: state.value + 1 }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const component2 = (state = { value: 10 }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return { ...state, value: state.value - 1 }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const reducer = combineReducers({
    component1: namespaced('component1')(component1),
    component2: namespaced('component2')(component2)
})

const store = createStore(reducer)

const component1Store = subspace((state) => state.subApp1, 'subApp1')(store)
const component2Store = subspace((state) => state.subApp2, 'subApp2')(store)

console.log('store state:', store.getState()) // { "component1": { "value": 1 }, "component2": { "value": 10 } }
console.log('component1Store state:', component1Store.getState()) // { "value": 1 }
console.log('component2Store state:', component2Store.getState()) // { "value": 10 }
```

Now dipatching actions into those sub-stores will also only affect their state

```
component1Store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT'})

console.log('store state:', store.getState()) // { "component1": { "value": 2 }, "component2": { "value": 10 } }
console.log('component1Store state:', component1Store.getState()) // { "value": 2 }
console.log('component2Store state:', component2Store.getState()) // { "value": 10 }

component2Store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT'})

console.log('store state:', store.getState()) // { "component1": { "value": 2 }, "component2": { "value": 10 } }
console.log('component1Store state:', component1Store.getState()) // { "value": 2 }
console.log('component2Store state:', component2Store.getState()) // { "value": 10 }
```

Notice that the `INCREMENT` action dipatched into the `component2Store` did not change the state of `component1Store`.  The situation is reversed if we dispatch a `DECREMENT` action

```
component1Store.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT'})

console.log('store state:', store.getState()) // { "component1": { "value": 2 }, "component2": { "value": 10 } }
console.log('component1Store state:', component1Store.getState()) // { "value": 2 }
console.log('component2Store state:', component2Store.getState()) // { "value": 10 }

component2Store.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT'})

console.log('store state:', store.getState()) // { "component1": { "value": 2 }, "component2": { "value": 9 } }
console.log('component1Store state:', component1Store.getState()) // { "value": 2 }
console.log('component2Store state:', component2Store.getState()) // { "value": 9 }
```

At this point, you would need to work out how to inject these sub-stores into your shared components.

Hope this is useful for you.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of redux-subspace

Comment: But if I map my store to somewhat exactly replicate my backend DB, then there should not be any clashes in items in the store. In such case why would one use redux-subspace?

Comment: It may or may not be for you (no hard feelings if not).  The main advantage of redux-subspace is that your `SM1` store has a known starting point for it's state, so `app1` and `app2` can combine the `SM1` reducer anywhere they want into theirs (e.g. different levels of nesting, different keys, etc.).  The other advantage is the actions from `SM1` get namespaces, so they won't be any cross-talk with other sub-modules using actions with the same action types.  This isolation makes future maintenance easier as each app evolves and more and more sub-modules (or even sub-sub-modules) are added.